# Why don't delegates accept compatible return types

Tags: c#, delegates

```
delegate int test14();
class vb {
    static public short test() {
        return 45;
    }
}

//Main method
test14 hbd = vb.test; //not possible
```

So I have the delegate `test14` which accepts parameterless methods with `int` return type.
It is not possible to assign a method to it that does not have the exact same return type but has a compatible return type. That is the case here where a method with `short` return type can not be assigned to a delegate with `int` return type.

Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean "compatible"? Covariance/Contravariance isn't involved here. There might be an implicit or explicit cast, is that what you mean?

Comment: @gunr2171 No no, I mean why I can not assign a plan with return type short to a delegate with return type int. Like short is compatible with int.

Comment: Because an int is not a short. Again, what do you mean by "compatible"?

Comment: @gunr2171, I am sorry, I mean that a short can fit in an int. I understand that the return type has to be exactly the same. I am just saying why is that so? Why doesn't it work like in the example?